# Android : Time milliseconds to X day - X hours - x Minute - X seconds left

Tags: android, time

I save into a database the current time in milliseconds. I want to display how many days, hours, minutes and seconds are elapsed from the time of storage. I take the current time with System.currentTimeMillies().

Comment: Restore it as a Date type and start comparisons?

Answer (score 1):

Store a timestamp in the database whenever you update the data, and use this in conjunction with a method in [DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) to format it into a relative time span string.

Answer (score 1):

Try This You can find your answer

```
Date d1 = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 00, 16, 21, 59).getTime();
Date d2 = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 00, 01, 15, 59).getTime();

long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); //for counting days 

(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60)); //for counting hours
```

.....................
...................
 and so on